# SQL Injection Prevention in Python - is using parameterized query enough?

Tags: python, sql-injection

I have the following python code:

```
row = conn.execute('''SELECT admin FROM account WHERE password = ?''',
(request.headers.get('X-Admin-Pass'),)).fetchone()
```

My question is whether this code is secure for SQL injection? Since I use parameterized query it should be. However, since I am passing user information straight from the header, I am a little worried :)

Any thoughts about the issue?

Comment: Which SQL library are you using?

Comment: Let's just hope that this is an example code where you put the part you are hashing the password out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that you are inserting the data into the database will ensure that an SQL attack will not work, the execute method will automatically escape the parameters that you passed as a tuple as its second parameter to the query.

You are doing that correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If your module uses the [DBI specs](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/l), then you're parameterizing fine.  Unless you want to do research into preventing specific SQL attacks, paramterizing your queries is a good umbrella against SQL injection.